# How to multiply a 4x4 Matrix with a vector-array of arbitrary length?

Tags: javascript, webgl

When writing a specific scene in webgl, the usual procedure of transforming an object would be to define the original *vertex position data* and pass it to the vertex shader, where the *vertices* are multiplied with *matrices*, that hold the informations about perspective, translations, rotations and scale, so that the corresponding vertex shader code - for example - would look like this:

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelviewMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
```

The *modelviewMatrix* itself is then the result of the multiplication of the *viewMatrix* with the *modelMatrix*, which again are the results of successive matrix manipulations to translate, rotate and scale.

What I'd like to know now is, how this last link in the chain of multiplications works - the multiplication of a *mat4* with a vector array of arbitrary length.

```
someMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
```

That is because I'm writing on a webgl editor and I want to be able to save the vertex position data of the created *and transformed* 3D-objects without the need of adding information about matrix transformations but as raw position data, simply as {x, y, z, x, y, z, x, y, z, etc.}, just like the original array of vertices.

As a basic example, let's say we have the following vertices for a simple triangle:

```
var vertices = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0];
```

Then I create a *mat4* and *translate* it by `[2, 0, 0]`.

The function I need would then take this translated *mat4* and the *vertices* array as parameters, would multiply both and return an array of *translated* vertices like:

```
var translatedVertices = [2.0, 1.0, 0.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  3.0, -1.0, 0.0];
```

It seems obvious, that for multiplying a 4x4 matrix with a vector array, there has to be added a fourth value to it, so the first step should be to split the original *vec3* array and insert for each triple of values an additional `1.0`, to make it a *vec4* array, `[x, y, z] --> [x, y, z, 1]`, but apart from that, I have absolutely no idea how this JavaScript function should look like.

Comment: FYI: You can make your shader have `attribute vec4 vertexPosition;` and still only pass 3 values per vertex with `gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);`.  `w` defaults to 1 if not provided for an attribute so this `someMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);` can be simplified to `someMatrix * vertexPosition;`

Comment: Wow, I always thought, the data type of the attribute has to be equal to the _item size_ of the corresponding buffer, noted as second argument for `gl.vertexAttribPointer`. - Nice little trick! Thank you, gman!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

```
someMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
```

`someMatrix` is a 4x4 matrix and `vertexPosition` is ALWAYS a 3x1 matrix that is converted to a 4x1 matrix with the addition of the 1.0. So a 4x4 matrix multiplied by a 4x1 matrix will produce again a valid 4x1 matrix (i.e. the `gl_Position`). Note that a 4x1 matrix is a `vec4`.

So you never multiply with a vector of "arbitrary" length. When you pass the data down (i.e. your `vertices` variable) the system breaks them down into triplets, adds the 1.0 and does the 4x4 by 4x1 multiplication.

Comment: Thank you very much, gaitat! Why making things complicated when it could be that simple... ;-)